# Strange results in Mendeley Web Importer

Tags: mendeley

I get strange results in the Mendeley Web Importer on many of the pages in our website, lens.org. For example, this page: https://www.lens.org/lens/search shows a list of patents. I know that Mendeley doesn't really work with patents, so I wouldn't expect the Web Importer to detect anything to import. But when I click the button I get this:
[image]
Where do all those results come from?

The first result, "Room-temperature fabrication of transparent flexible thin-film transistors..." shows up in a lot of pages that it shouldn't. For example, on this page: https://www.lens.org/lens/scholar/article/091-863-869-534-178/main, clicking the Mendeley Web Importer button gives me 2 results when I expect to only get 1.
[image]
I've searched the page content for the DOI (10.1038/nature03090) but it doesn't appear to be there. There is only one `.Z3988` element on the page, and that is for the article displayed on the page. Where is the extra result coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once dropped the Mendeley Web Importer will try to find any references on the page. This means that sometimes it can find references that are not immediately visible to the user.

In your case, that DOI is actually present in the html, see:
[image]

For single article page such as https://www.lens.org/lens/scholar/article/091-863-869-534-178/main, the Mendeley Web Importer would be more accurate if Highwire Press tags were included in the `<head>`of the page. Example:

```html
<meta name="citation_title" content="Global and local fMRI signals driven by neurons defined optogenetically by type and wiring.">
<meta name="citation_authors" content="Lee, Jin Hyung; Durand, Remy; Gradinaru, Viviana; Zhang, Feng; Goshen, Inbal; Kim, Dae-Shik; Fenno, Lief E; Ramakrishnan, Charu; Deisseroth, Karl">
<meta name="citation_journal_title" content="Nature">
<meta name="citation_publisher" content="Nature Publishing Group">
<meta name="citation_issue" content="7299">
<meta name="citation_volume" content="465">
<meta name="citation_doi" content="10.1038/nature09108">
```

Cf https://www.mendeley.com/guides/information-for-publishers